# manipulate parameter on sql using mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I have query with where clause like

```
where value in (10,-10).
```

I have to implement this using mybatis and I tried something like

```
value IN (#{input},#{input}*-1)
```

And this is not working. I am using oracle db .
Any idea what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: i think you should use two placeholders instead. input and negInput set 10 and -10 in them and then use here.

Comment: That is possible. But I am looking something that can be done on sql side.

Comment: What about #{-input}

Comment: that didn't work.